# Entity Framework 5.0. What is wrong with my Query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is my code:

```
public DateTime GibSomeStartDate(IEnumerable<int> partnerNumbers, DateTime startTime)
{
     var contractsStartDate = from contract in this.databaseContext.Contract
                              where partnerNumbers.Contains(contract.Pnr) 
                                 && contract.SomeDateTime >= startTime
                              select contract.SomeDateTime;
}
```

if I call `contractsStartDate.Min()` an Exception occurs:

```
Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.
```

What is wrong with my Query?

- the `contractsStartDate` is of type
  `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`
- EF 5.0
- `databaseContext` is child of `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow has the rigth answer ) it was null :(  Thank you! )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this error. Just Make sure `partnerNumbers` is not null. You're passing a null value for this parameter, but Linq-to-entities can't translate that value to anything meaningful.

```
if (partnerNumbers == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("partnerNumbers");
}
```

An additional bonus advice:

If `SomeDateTime` is `not nullable` and there are no entries in your enumeration, then you'll get an exception on calling `Min()`. Casting `SomeDateTime` to the `nullable` type in your query will work, then you get null when there are no entries.

Comment: Thank you - Ill check your advice now

Comment: For future reference, the clue was in the exception: a LINQ/EF query returns an `IQueryable`, not an `IEnumerable`, so the parameter was the only obvious `IEnumerable` in scope.  :)  (Well, technically, `IQueryable` is also an `IEnumerable`, but the error will show the most specific type.)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - please use "@" in your comments - like "@GalacticCowboys" - than Ill be informed about new information. Thank you for IQueryable and IEnumerable. But I havent understood this "clue" :)

Comment: @MikroDel It was a general comment, not necessarily directed at you.  Debugging stuff like this can be challenging, but rewarding.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - sure I have debuged it before I have post my question