# Entity Framework 5.0. Something like "any of" Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is my code from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363337/entity-framework-5-0-what-is-wrong-with-my-query):

```
public DateTime GibSomeStartDate(IEnumerable<int> partnerNumbers, DateTime startTime)
{
     var contractsStartDate = from contract in this.databaseContext.Contract
                              where partnerNumbers.Contains(contract.Pnr) 
                                 && contract.SomeDateTime >= startTime
                              select contract.SomeDateTime;
}
```

*I hope it will not be flagged or downvoted cause its an another question even though with the same code.*

I want to return only `contractsStartDate`(s) that contains any of `partnerNumbers` in `contract.Pnr`.

For example if `partnerNumbers` are 1, 2, 3 and there are `contracts` with `Pnr` 1, 3, 4 and 7 - four `contract` Instances - than I need `contract`(s) which have `Pnr` 1 and 3

With my `where partnerNumbers.Contains(contract.Pnr)` I check the exact match - and that is not what I want.

- the `contractsStartDate` is of type
  `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`
- EF 5.0
- `databaseContext` is child of `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

*Updated*

- `Contract` is an `Entity`. `Pnr` is `int` property

Comment: What is `contract.Pnr`?

Comment: What do you want instead of an exact match?

Comment: @IronMan84 - I have updated my answer with the information you asked for

Comment: @MatthewWalton - I have updated my answer with the answer :) for your question

Comment: @MikroDel Isn't that what your code already does? Except that you should add a Distinct() to your query. You first select all contracts that have a "Pnr" contained in your enumeration partnerNumbers, and then select the someDate of each contract.

Comment: You say an exact match isn't what you want.  If 'Pnr' is an int what do you want?  If Pnr = 12345 and partner numbers contains say 123, 678, 135 do you want it match on the 123?

Comment: @Phil - in your example I need no matches - empty

Comment: I've read this question ~10 times already and still have absolutely no clue what you want to achieve (that your code doesn't already do).

Comment: The code looks right to me then, I've used `Contains` that way many times and it always works nicely.

Comment: Pretty sure the code you've posted already does what you say you want. Test it yourself and see...

Comment: Please explain the issue. Are you encountering a compile time exception, run-time exception, or you are getting an incorrect result. If you are getting an incorrect result, please explain why.

Comment: You are right its work! :) Sorry!

Comment: Why is it happened? Cause I have tetsted it wrong!

Comment: Please mark as solved :   is this a **PICNIC** ?
Problem in Chair not in computer :-)

Comment: Your code does what you need, but maybe the '&& contract.SomeDateTime >= startTime' eliminates some results so you mistakenly think it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work good Sorry!

Why is it happened? Cause I have tetsted it wrong! )